# Setting SQL Server Properties Connections

Tags: sql, powershell

I am trying to set the Server Connection options using SMO. My goal is to set the Default Connection Options such as xact abort, ansi padding... this is what I have but cannot see it in the configuration

```
$instance = (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo");
$SQL = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($env:ComputerName)
$conn = $SQL.ConnectionContext;
$conn.LoginSecure = $false
$conn.Login = "sa"
$conn.Password = "Sample"
$sql2 = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($conn)
$sql.Configuration.MaxServerMemory.ConfigValue = 6144
$sql.Configuration.Alter()
```

Would anyone have an insight on how to enable the connection options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another way to accomplish what I needed to do. Here is how I did it:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo");
$SQL = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($env:ComputerName)
$conn = $SQL.ConnectionContext;
$conn.LoginSecure = $false
$conn.Login = "sa"
$conn.Password = "Sample"
$sql2 = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($conn)
$sql.Configuration.MaxServerMemory.ConfigValue = 6144
$sql.Configuration.Alter()

$con = "Server=Localhost;uid=sa;pwd=Sample; Database=Master"
$MSSQl = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$MSSQl.ConnectionString = $con
$MSSQl.Open()
$query = "sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options' , 1;EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote query timeout (s)', N'0';EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', N'21880';RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;"
$cmd = $MSSQL.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $query
$result = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
$MSSQL.Close()
```

So the way I achieved this was using the Management Studio and selecting all the options and left-clicking on **Script**. I then run the script in a query

Comment: Simpler way for SQL 2016+:  `Import-Module -Name SQLServer; 
$Instance.Configuration.MaxServerMemory.ConfigValue=6144; 
$Instance.Configuration.Alter()`